# Javascript query

Tags: jquery

i've been using the Raptorize Jquery plugin and was wondering if anyone knows how to offset the image so its off the page to start with and moves across. (I have no clue how to work Javascript)

hope you can help

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.raptorize = function(options) {

        //Yo' defaults
        var defaults = {  
            enterOn: 'click', //timer, konami-code, click
            delayTime: 5000 //time before raptor attacks on timer mode
            };  

        //Extend those options
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

        return this.each(function() {

            var _this = $(this);
            var audioSupported = false;
            //Stupid Browser Checking which should be in jQuery Support
            if ($.browser.mozilla && $.browser.version.substr(0, 5) >= "1.9.2" || $.browser.webkit) { 
                audioSupported = true;
            }

            //Raptor Vars
            var raptorImageMarkup = '<img id="elRaptor" style="display: none" src="raptor.png" />'
            var raptorAudioMarkup = '<audio id="elRaptorShriek" preload="auto"><source src="raptor-sound.mp3" /><source src="raptor-sound.ogg" /></audio>'; 
            var locked = false;

            //Append Raptor and Style
            $('body').append(raptorImageMarkup);
            if(audioSupported) { $('body').append(raptorAudioMarkup); }
            var raptor = $('#elRaptor').css({
                "position":"fixed",
                "bottom": "0px",
                "right" : "0",
                "display" : "block"
            })

            // Animating Code
            function init() {
                locked = true;

                //Sound Hilarity
                if(audioSupported) { 
                    function playSound() {
                        document.getElementById('elRaptorShriek').play();
                    }
                    playSound();
                }

                // Movement Hilarity    
                raptor.animate({
                    "bottom" : "0"
                }, function() {             
                    $(this).animate({
                        "bottom" : "0px"
                    }, 100, function() {
                        var offset = (($(this).position().left)+600);
                        $(this).delay(300).animate({
                            "right" : offset
                        }, 2300, function() {

                            raptor = $('#elRaptor').css({
                                "bottom": "-700px",
                                "right" : "300"
                            })
                            locked = false;
                        })
                    });
                });
            }


            //Determine Entrance
            if(options.enterOn == 'timer') {
                setTimeout(init, options.delayTime);
            } else if(options.enterOn == 'click') {
                _this.bind('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(!locked) {
                        init();
                    }
                })
            } else if(options.enterOn == 'konami-code'){
                var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
                $(window).bind("keydown.raptorz", function(e){
                    kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
                    if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
                        init();
                        $(window).unbind('keydown.raptorz');
                    }
                }, true);

            }

        });//each call
    }//orbit plugin call
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can offset the image using the "right" property, just set it to the negative width (this presumes that the image has a width though, which it should as it is appended to the body).

For example:

```
 var raptor = $('#elRaptor').css({
                "position":"fixed",
                "bottom": "0px",
                "right" : -$("#elRaptor").width(),
                "display" : "block"
              });
```

I have created a small sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrjrU/), wait three seconds and the "raptor" starts walking from the bottom right of the screen to the bottom left.

A better way to detect audio support is using Modernizr, refer to http://modernizr.com/docs/.

Comment: Hi strmstn, can you give me an example of how you would do this? I can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is a little different from the original plugin version. The difference results in the raptor starting out on the page rather than hidden and out of the view.

Update css `bottom` attribute from 0px to -700px:

```js
var raptor = $('#elRaptor').css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "bottom": "-700px", // Update bottom from 0px to -700px
    "right": "0",
    "display" : "block"
});
```

Side Note: It's been a long time since original raptorize plugin was released (2010) and it stopped working with newer jQuery versions. There is an updated implementation (https://github.com/randomvlad/raptorize-jquery) that supports jQuery versions 1.7+, 2.x and 3.x along with a few extra improvements.

Disclaimer: I'm the "author" of the updated raptorize 2.0 plugin, which itself is based on the original one by ZURB (https://zurb.com/playground/jquery-raptorize).